# List variables in Java

Tags: java, list, boolean

Okay, might not be the right title, but here's what I'm thinking. I am looking for a way to loop through a set of variables. For example, I'm thinking in my game there would be a series of things you could unlock, and when you entered "unlocked" or something it would show you what you had unlocked and **only** what you had unlocked. So it would show **only** the Booleans that  were false.

Comment: Even though this is incredibly unorthodox - you want the user to be able to query about *variables*, which isn't a good sign right off the bat - is it the case that they will always be asking about the specific variables of your class?

Comment: This makes no sense.  You have two variables with the same name.  But perhaps you need to use java Reflexion.

Answer (score 5):

In Java, there is no easy way to get a variable based on its name. What you can do, however, is store all your variables in a `HashMap`. This will accomplish what you want.

```
HashMap<String, Boolean> vars = new HashMap<>();
vars.put("test1", true); // to make a new variable
vars.get("test1"); // to get a variable's value
```

If you want to store any variable type, change the statement that creates the list of variables.

```
HashMap<String, Object> vars = new HashMap<>();
```

---

To find **only** the `booleans` that are `false`, you can simply iterate over the `HashMap`, like so:

```
for(Entry<String, Boolean> entry : vars.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    boolean value = entry.getValue();

    if(!value) {
        System.out.println(key + " was false");
    }
}
```

There is a comprehensive tutorial [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html), if you want to learn more about maps in Java.

Comment: it's only unsignificantly slower. HashMaps are very fast

Comment: That's true. I was thinking that it might be slower comparatively then one can do in `JavaScript`, but that's irrelevant to Java.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a method that returns a collection of keys that have a false values. Depending on your requirements (if it's a homework assignment or something) there are a couple of ways you could do it. If it is required to use only primitives, you could do something like

```
public List<String> getUnlockedItems(Map<String, Boolean> map) {
    // map validation (not null, has entries, etc)
    final List<String> unlockedEntries = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> entry : map.entries()) {
        if (entry.getValue() == true) {// if it has been unlocked
            unlockedEntries.add(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
    return unlockedEntries;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Boolean> unlockables = new HashMap<>();
    unlockables.put("Fire Punch", false);
    unlockables.put("Ice Punch", false);
    unlockables.put("Mega Punch", false);
    unlockables.put("Thunder Punch", false);

    // Player unlocks Fire Punch
    unlockables.put("Fire Punch", true);

    // Get list of unlockables they have unlocked
    List<String> unlockedItems = getUnlockedItems(unlockables); // returns ["Fire Punch"]
}
```

If you're able to define your own types, it may be better in terms of maintainability and readability to do something like

```
public class Unlockable {

    public Unlockable(String name) {
        // name validation
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void unlock() {
        unlocked = true;
    }

    public boolean isUnlocked() {
        return unlocked;
    }

    private String name;
    private boolean unlocked;
}
```

And then something like

```
public List<Unlockable> getUnlockedItems(List<Unlockable> unlockables) {
    List<Unlockable> unlockedItems = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Unlockable unlockable : unlockables) {
        if (unlockable.isUnlocked()) {
            unlockedItems.add(unlockable);
        }
    }
    return unlockedItems;
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Unlockable firePunch = new Unlockable("Fire Punch");
    Unlockable icePunch = new Unlockable("Ice Punch");
    Unlockable megaPunch = new Unlockable("Mega Punch");
    Unlockable thunderPunch = new Unlockable("Thunder Punch");

    List<Unlockable> unlockables = new ArrayList<>();
    unlockables.add(firePunch);
    unlockables.add(icePunch);
    unlockables.add(megaPunch);
    unlockables.add(thunderPunch);

    // Player unlocks Fire Punch
    firePunch.unlock();

    // Get list of unlockables they have unlocked
    List<Unlockable> unlockedItems = getUnlockedItems(unlockables); // returns ["Fire Punch"]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use a [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

```
Map<String, Boolean> m = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
m.put("test1", false);
m.put("test2", true);
```

**Usage:**

```
System.out.println("is test1 " + m.get("test1"));
```

Comment: Why downvote this? Apart from the missing generics, it's sensible

Comment: Why have you edited to remove the diamond operator ?

Comment: Merely saying, "Just use X" without any context into *why* X is better isn't helpful.  You're more than likely correct, but you don't bother explaining *why*.  That's what you're missing here.

Comment: You need to have the `key` as a `Object` so by that way you could have any kind of values you want. Then you will be able to go over all the values in the map and ask: `if (m.get(<some key>) instanceof Boolean) {...}`

Comment: I need a way to have it say only booleans that are true. also couldnt I just go like this:   boolean test1 = false;
  System.out.println("test1 is" +test1);

Comment: Ok, but you say that you need it for all boolean values, sounds like you got not only boolean inside this map, so you need to go over all the keys like I said